# Javascript Incrementer

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Incrementer()
{
    debugger;
    var txtBox = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value;
    int i = parseInt(txtBox);
    i = i + 1;
    var v = i + "";
    document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value = v;
   alert(v);
}

</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Up"  OnClientClick="Incrementer();"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Down" runat="server"/>
    </asp:Content>
```

I am unable to increment the value in javascript....what is the problem?

Comment: `int i` isn't valid Javascript, is it?

Comment: ohhhh ...smarty goreSplatter....Thanks , issue resolved.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no int in javascript. 
Variables are always declared with var.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HMC9V/

Answer (score 0):

int i = parseInt(txtBox); this line is incorrect. 
int doesn't used in Javascript for declaring variables. 
It should be corrected to var i = parseInt(txtBox);